# Gradual slowdown of h5write function in Julia HDF5 package

Tags: hdf5, julia

**EDIT:** Based on additional experimentation, I'm fairly confident the slow-down occurs in response to many calls to the file open and close routines (`h5open` and `close`). I'm a bit short on time right now, but will come back and add more code/detail in the next few days.

Using the HDF5 package for Julia, I've noticed that the `h5write` function starts to slow down if one performs many iterations over calls to `h5write` and `h5read`. Interestingly, it appears that for the behaviour to be really obvious, one should be reading and writing to a large number of locations in a small number of files. A demonstration of the behaviour I'm talking about can be obtained by starting a Julia session and running the following subroutine (note, you will need the HDF5 package):

```
#Set parameters
numFile = 10;
numLocation = 10000;
writeDir = "/home/colin/Temp/";
FloatOut = 5.5;

#Import functions
using HDF5

#Loop over read/writes.
c1 = 1;
timeMat = Array(Float64, numFile * 2, 2);  
for i in 1:numFile
    filePath = string(writeDir, "f", string(i), ".h5");
    for j in 1:numLocation
        location = string("G1/L", string(j));
        if j == 1 || j == numLocation; tic(); end;      
        h5write(filePath, location, FloatOut);
        if j == 1 || j == numLocation; timeMat[c1, 1] = toc(); end;
        if j == 1 || j == numLocation; tic(); end;
        FloatIn = h5read(filePath, location);
        if j == 1 || j == numLocation; timeMat[c1, 2] = toc(); end;
        if j == 1 || j == numLocation; c1 = c1+1; end;  
    end
    rm(filePath);
end
```

This code writes the floating point number `5.5` (chosen for no particular reason) to `10,000` locations in each of `10` files using `h5write`. Immediately after performing the write operation each time, the number is then read back in using `h5read`. For each file, I store the time taken to perform the write and read operation to the first and last location for each file in `timeMat` (note: initially, I stored the timing for *every* call but this level of detail is unnecessary to demonstrate the anomaly for the purposes of this question). The times are printed below:

```
h5write  h5read
0.0007   0.0004
0.0020   0.0004
0.0020   0.0004
0.0031   0.0004
0.0034   0.0004
0.0049   0.0004 
0.0050   0.0004
0.0064   0.0005
0.0068   0.0004
0.0082   0.0004
0.0084   0.0005
0.0106   0.0005
0.0114   0.0005
0.0114   0.0005
0.0120   0.0005
0.0131   0.0005
0.0135   0.0005
0.0146   0.0005
0.0151   0.0005 
0.0163   0.0005
```

The timings for `h5read` are fairly consistent across the subroutine. However, the timings for `h5write` gradually get slower. By the end, a write is taking an order of magnitude longer than at the start. I understand that for each file, as we increase the number of locations, the time for a write (and read) might get slightly slower. But in this case, the slower performance persists even after we begin a new file. Perhaps strangest of all, we can run the subroutine a second time and time taken for a write will pick up where we left off on the previous run. The only way to get the time taken for a write back to the fastest speed is to completely restart Julia.

Final disclaimer: I am brand new to both Julia and hdf5, so I may have done something stupid or be overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slowdown is indeed curious; [profiling](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/profile/) shows that almost all the time is spent in the `close` function, which is basically just a `ccall`. This suggests it may be a problem with the HDF5 C-library itself.

I think you'll be rather happier with the performance if you don't open and close the file each time you write a variable; instead, access the file through a file object. Here's an example:

```
filePath = string(writeDir, "f", string(i), ".h5")
h5open(filePath, "w") do file
    global c1
    for j in 1:numLocation
        ...
        write(file, location, FloatOut)
        ...
        FloatIn = read(file, location)
        ...
    end
end
```

This way you're leaving the file open throughout the test. On my machine this is something like 100x faster.

If you want to pursue this further, please submit an [issue](https://github.com/timholy/HDF5.jl/issues?state=open).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I had a look at the package source code and was also slowly coming to the conclusion that the problem might be in the C-library. I am in the 99.99% of users for which the slow-down is not a problem (particularly when opening and closing outside a loop of writes), so I won't submit an issue. I figure this SO question is a sufficiently good starting point for anyone else who wants to dive into it. Cheers, and thanks for a great package! I'll be using it extensively in the coming months.

Comment: I noticed a similar problem with h5py (Python hdf5-bindings). Another indication that the hdf5 C library is to blame for this...

Comment: Thanks to you both for digging into this.